Listen to Google Meet events
According to https://developers.google.com/workspace/events, I can subscribe to Google Meet events using Pub/Sub. It supports 2 target resources: meeting spaces and users.
As per link, for users, the target resource is //cloudidentity.googleapis.com/users/USER_ID — How do I get the USER_ID?
The tutorial only shows meeting spaces: https://developers.google.com/meet/api/guides/tutorial-events-python.
It seems that I can get it from Cloud Identity, but how do I use it for non-Workspace users (i.e. @gmail.com users)?
My goal is to create a service where people can register using Google OAuth 2.0, and receive a summary of their meeting (where they're the owner) right after it's ended.

I'm unsure but I think you cannot do this for non-Workspace (e.g. Gmail) users
